# Equation setting

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have a problem with this equation compilation at the end{split}
please fix it.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   \frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}}(\rho \bar u_i \bar u_j) = -\frac{\partial \bar p}{\partial X_{j}} + \frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}}[\mu (\frac{\partial \bar u_i}{\partial X_{j}}+\frac{\partial \bar u_j}{\partial X_{i}} -\frac 23\delta_{ij}\frac{\partial \bar u_l}{\partial X_{l}}) ]+ \frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}}(-\rho  \bar u{_i^'}  \bar u_{j}^{'}) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to think that `split` will automatically divide the formula across lines, but this isn't true: the line breaks must be specified manually. Please, make the example into a minimal document from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Change the last term into `(-\rho\bar u{_i'}  \bar u{_j'})` should compile.

Comment: @Jesse `\bar u{_i'}` is wrong: `\bar{u}_{i}'` is correct syntax

Comment: @egreg  Wow, interesting. Not until now --- my math typing could be wrong in the past.

Answer (score 3):

while mico's answer addresses how `split` is used, i think the problem addressed by the
question has to do with the use of `'` to indicate "prime".

`'` will automatically be treated as a prime; there is no need to explicitly superscript it
or to enclose it in braces.  *how* it is applied depends on the intended meaning.  i think
there are two possibilities here, and will show just the last segment of the expression.

if the prime is applied to the main part of the expression:

```
\[
\frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}}(-\rho  \bar u_{i}'  \bar u_{j}') 
\]
```

if the prime is applied to the subscript:

```
\[
\frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}}(-\rho  \bar u_{i'}  \bar u_{j'}) 
\]
```

also note that braces delineating a sub- (or super)script should be placed *after* the
script indicator (`_` or `^`), not before.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `split` environment inside an `equation` environment, be sure to (a) insert alignment points and (b) provide line breaks. Incidentally, I've changed some of the material in the last line of equation-related code as your posting wouldn't compile as is; I hope my modifications jibe with what you're hoping to get.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   \frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}}(\rho \bar u_i \bar u_j) 
   &= -\frac{\partial \bar p}{\partial X_{j}} + 
   \frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}} \biggl[
   \mu \biggl( \frac{\partial \bar u_i}{\partial X_{j}}+
   \frac{\partial \bar u_j}{\partial X_{i}} -
   \frac 23\delta_{ij} \frac{\partial \bar u_l}{\partial X_{l}}
   \biggr) \biggr]\\
   &\qquad+ \frac{\partial }{\partial X_{j}}(-\rho \bar u_i' \bar u_j')
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```